# Can I get the content of a conversation with one of my contacts that I made using WhatsApp calls (not chat)?

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, calls

I would like to know if I can get the content of a conversation with one of my contacts that I made using WhatsApp calls (not chat), or if the information is stored in my phone and how I can get it.

I already contacted WhatsApp Team, but it looks like they are going to take a while to respond.

What do I need to know to get that information?

Comment: Are you asking if WhatsApp recorded a voice call without your knowledge and saved it locally for you just in case?  That seems ... unlikely.

Comment: Yes, So there is no way to get it?  I need it to prove fraud !!!

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't. The content of the call isn't stored on your phone.